# How to change NPM version?

Tags: javascript, npm, package

I am trying to install some packages for React-Native project but its shows me NPM version error so, How can I upgrade.

**My current version is 4**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hey for updating npm just fire this command in terminal

```
npm i npm@5 -g
```

here -g is for global if you want to install only for one project then just remove -g from this.
Thanks, Hope this will help you.